# Is there a faster, easier way to write several if statements with multiple AND conditions?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there an easy way to cater for all the possible combinations without having to manually write all of these if statements?

```
var ups;
var trans;
var sat;
var kplc;

 if(ups === 'false' && trans ==='true'&& sat ==='true' && kplc ==='true'){
            //do something
}
 if(ups === 'true' && trans ==='true'&& sat ==='true' && kplc ==='true'){
            //do something
}
 if(ups === 'false' && trans ==='false'&& sat ==='true' && kplc ==='true'){
            //do something
}
 if(ups === 'false' && trans ==='true'&& sat ==='false' && kplc ==='true'){
            //do something
}
////and so forth and so forth....
```

Comment: I see only a single `if` statement..? Do you mean you have one for each combination?

Comment: Why are these strings?

Comment: The answer to this depends on the requirement.  If there is to be a different event to happen for each and every combination of your four booleans, then you need all the branches.  If, however, the action to be taken can be grouped in some way, then the answer would be different.

Comment: I have like 10 so far, but it's getting quite troublesome

Comment: Rather than adding a clause for each combination, I'd look at the dependent code and see if there was a better way to refactor it. As it stands, there appear to be 16 (2^4) possible combinations.

Comment: To reduce code I would transform it first to boolean value and then just say `if (!ups && trans && sat && kplc)`. If you need them as strings then I don't see any better option than creating some functions to make the code more readable. Equally is not that nice.

Comment: We can't tell you the answer here though with what you have supplied, this is the nuts and bolts of programming, being able to find the minimum necessary number of paths through the code you write.  If you post your ten so far, we may be able to steer you.

Comment: @Paddy I've added more

Comment: So, thanks for those, however they don't really help.  The important thing when deciding how you can minimise these is how many different 'do somethings' you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if all of your values passes the same predicate, you can put all of the values in an array and use Array.prototype.every.

```
let foo = true
let bar = true
let baz = false

if ([foo, bar, baz].every(value => value === true)) {
  console.log('condition passed')
}
```

Likewise to check if at least one of them passes the predicate, use Array.protoype.some

```
let foo = true
let bar = true
let baz = false

if ([foo, bar, baz].some(value => value === true)) {
  console.log('condition passed')
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, let me try it out

Comment: Is there a way to print out the variable which was true as well?

Comment: `findIndex`. But honestly, `foo && bar && baz` or `foo + bar + baz > 1` is shorter and more reasable.

Comment: This would only look at whether foo, bar, and baz are either all true, or at least one of them is true. That's only 2 results. I believe the question is looking for an answer that tells us *which* of the variables are true.